# Visual Studio 2022, XUnit test project, cannot inspect object properties if the class has a property of a Type from NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2022, xunit

We tried this with both VS 2022 17.8.3, 17.9.0 and 17.9.1 which is currently the latest.

**Symptom:**
When running XUnit test and hitting a breakpoint and we try to inspect properties of an object it just hangs for a while with a message "Busy" then in the Watch window if we expand the object it just shows three ellipsis. This happens only if the object has at least one property with a Type defined in a NuGet package.

XUnit test with breakpoint, goint to inspect variable **s**:

[image: XUnit test with breakpoint]

Watch window shows nothing when expanding variable, just "...":

[image: Watch window shows nothing when expanding variable]

---

**"Workaround":**
A "workaround" is to instantiate an object of a Type from the NuGet package before inspecting.

[image: Workaround]

It now works to inspect the variable "s".

---

It is pretty obvious that the problem occurs because the dll from the NuGet is not yet loaded when we inspect the object. Is there any setting in VS we might have missed, or could it be something in our codebase?

Comment: Could you please share reproduce test code?

Comment: It is a private NuGet feed that I cannot share. But I will try to reproduce the issue in a new solution with a public NuGet